# Pascal program exercise

Tags: pascal

I am at the beginning with my studies and would like to ask a question regarding a function in pascal. The aim is to calculate the Fahrenheit value in Celsius. The formula is as follows:  `C = [5 * (F - 32)] / 9`.

The user should put in his value and it should result in the correct number. 
My program is so far:

```
Program Temperaturerrechnung (input, output);  
var  
C: real;  
F: real;  
begin  
    writeln('Insert Fahrenheit', F);  
    readln(F);  
    C:= (5 * (F - 32)) / 9  
    writeln('The temperature is C: ', C)  
end
```

When compiling, it tells me that `F` has not identified.

Comment: I think you can't `readLn` into a `real` variable. You'd have to have a separate `text` variable and then cast it to `real` (don't remember the syntax for that, though... it might be `StrToFloat` depending on which version of Pascal you are using)

Comment: Works fine with Free Pascal after adding a semicolon after the " / 9 ". If you have problems entering data and you are in a locale with a comma as decimal separator, try to use point as decimal separator too

Answer (score 3):

You have a few problems there:

```
writeln('Insert Fahrenheit', F);
```

The `F` variable is not initialized here, that means you have never assigned it a value. In this case I believe you don't want it in the output at all:

```
writeln('Insert Fahrenheit');
```

Also, you are missing `;` after `C:= (5 * (F - 32)) / 9`.